# RStudio: Build and reload adds blank line to 'suggests' field in DESCRIPTION file

Tags: r, rstudio, roxygen2

whenever I run a `Build & Reload` from RStudio's `Build` pane, I get the message

```
==> Rcmd.exe INSTALL --no-multiarch rwiots    
Error: contains a blank line
```

and, indeed, when I look, my DESCRIPTION file contains a blank line in the `Suggests` field. If I delete this, it's created again when I try to `Build & Reload`.

I have the option `Generate documentation with Roxygen` ticked and all boxes ticked in the `Configure...` dialog that goes with it.

I really enjoy the workflow of documenting my functions with roxygen2 and having RStudio build my NAMESPACE file and parts of my DESCRIPTION file. So how can I get past this very odd little problem?

Many thanks in advance,
Rob Levy

Comment: How did you create the DESCRIPTION?

Comment: Good question. I think it must have been with `skeleton`. Or, more likely, I did `Create new project` in RStudio with the `package` option selected under `Type`.

Comment: Is it possible to delete the description file and have "something" rebuild it for me properly, in the case where I've done something wrong?

Comment: What happens if you delete the entire suggests element?

Comment: It works! Thanks Hadley. Keep up the (insanely) good work building support for R and making it great!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hadley had the key:

If there's a `Suggests:` region in the `DESCRIPTION` file, but you're not suggesting anything, the `Build & Reload` functionality in RStudio adds a blank line, which then breaks the build process!

Comment: I think that's a roxygen2 bug :/